# How to have a paragraph text in a table column in which the table is aligned with text width?

Tags: tables, paragraphs

I have the following table with two columns and one of them requires longer text and i need the table to fit with the text width. Hence, i am using two columns page style as IEEE or ACM conferences.

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ || l | l || }
\hline \hline
    BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAA AAAAA AAAA AA  \\ \hline
    sssss & dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd dddddddddddddddddddddd  dddddd ddd ddd \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\label{xxxx}
\caption{zzzzzzzz}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use as much width as allowed (`\columnwidth`) you can use tabularx.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE only

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[h]
%\centering% no gap to fill
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{ || l | X || }
\hline \hline
    BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAA AAAAA AAAA AA  \\ \hline
    sssss & dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd dddddddddddddddddddddd  dddddd ddd ddd \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\label{xxxx}
\caption{zzzzzzzz}
\end{table}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add argument `p` to allow paragraphs in a cell (instead of `l`), the size of the column can be adjusted using value in `p{size}`, as below

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ || p{1in} | p{1in} ||}
%\hline \hline commented out
    BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAA AAAAA AAAA AA  \\ \hline
    sssss & dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd dddddddddddddddddddddd  dddddd ddd ddd \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\label{xxxx}
\caption{zzzzzzzz}
\end{table}
```